# WiFi service stops after system resumes

Tags: wifi, suspend

After resuming the system from suspend, the WiFi service stops working and wifi icon disappears. 
I tried registering a service at **/etc/systemd/system/resume-wifi.service** folder.

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

But for activating the service, I tried using systemctl which is not found  in elementary os packages.
Used this link for above: [AskUbuntu Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638124/no-wifi-after-suspend-on-15-04/642559). Please suggest how to resume the service in this OS. Thanks.